# Is it good idea to use AngularJS to display product search results on public website

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, pusher

I want to know the pros/cons of using AngularJS on public pages of my website where I want to show product search results. It will have product images, prices, other info and buy button.

The results will be displayed by push technology using pusher.com or a similar setup.

Is it wise to use AngularJS app for this scenario? Or is it better to use jquery with pusher-js to display the results? Which one is best practice and easy to manage edit later w.r.t. design as well?

Thank you

Comment: There won't be any issue whichever language used.Ultimately its your choice. AngularJS will be the good option though, as its is pretty simple and easy to do things

Comment: @PravinErande what about design changes in the search results? will that be easy if using angularjs? if I provide this script to someone, will it be easier for them to edit search listings in angularjs rather than html?